# Same UITableView in different viewcontrollers?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, uitableview, uiviewcontroller

I have an application that has multiple viewcontrollers and one common menu table.

Menu table is same in all viewcontrollers. Currently, If i want to add some more menu in my menu table then I have to change in all the view controllers.

Can we have a common table view which can be called in different viewcontrollers?

Thanks

Comment: Declare an Array in Appdellegate And Share its Value among All View Controllers. Make Changes in this Array And All table will be affected.

Comment: Thanks for your response. But what about other methods. Still I have to change in multiple places like tableview:didselect method etc.

Comment: Take a common Array for All the Views And assign them the Values from AppDelegate.

Comment: Hi dilip did you get the solution for this?

Answer (score 2):

Make a subclass of `UITableView` and create your menu in that like :

```
@interface menuTable : UITableView
```

Then you can use the instance of that class in all `viewControllers`.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can. 
When you add UIView to some other UIView, former will be removed from it's Superview and added to latter as subview. Remember to be careful with view's frame. e.g. convert it using `convertRect:toView:` selector

Comment: Thanks for your response. But I think you didn't get my question correctly.

Comment: I thought you mean "the same instance". Sometimes it makes sense.

Answer (score 0):

As I understand ur question, just **create a tableView in  CommonView (a ref. name) and as per your need you can call that table view.** By this way you have to not change many times in your code.